# How to write NA for missing results in rvest if there was no content in node (within loop) further how to merge variable with results

Tags: r, loops, merge, na, rvest

Hi i'm new to R and try to fetch the tickers/symbols of Yahoo Finance from a text file which contains company names like Adidas, BMW etc. in order to run an event study later. This file contains about 800 names. Some of them can be found in yahoo and some not. (Thats ok)

My loop work so far but missing results won't be displayed. Further it only creates a table with numbers and results which could be found.But i would like to create a list which displayed the variable i ("firmen") and the results that's has been found or an NA in case there was no result.

**Hope you guys can help me. Thank you !!!**

my code:

```
library(rvest)

# company_names
firmen <- c(read.table("Mappe1.txt"))

# init
df <- NULL

# loop for search names in Yahoo Ticker Lookup
for(i in firmen){
  # find url
  url <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup/all?s=", i, "/")
  page <- read_html(url,as="text")

# grab table
  table <- page %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='lookup-page']/section/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    as.data.frame()

# bind to dataframe
  df <- rbind(df, table)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the first problem and now empty nodes (if "i" has not been found on the yahoo page) will be displayed as "NA"

here is the code:

```
  library(rvest)

# teams
firmen <- c(read.table("Mappe1.txt"))

# init
df <- NULL
table <- NULL

# loop
for(i in firmen){
  # find url
  url <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup/all?s=", i, "/")
  page <- read_html(url,as="text")
  # grab ticker from yahoo finance
  table <- page %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='lookup-page']/section/div/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]") %>%
    html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% replace(!nzchar(table), NA) %>%
    as.data.frame()
  
  # bind to dataframe

  df <- rbind(df,table)
}
```

**Now there is just one question left**

How can i merge "df" and "firmen" into one table which has the columns:

"tickers" = df  and "firmen" = firmen

because df has just one column named "." with the results and the list firmen contains a number of companies placed in many colums but with just one row.

basically i need to transform the list "firmen" but i don't know how

Thank you for the help